# Child element click triggering parent element as well - Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The code is as follows

```
<ul className="sb-modules-list">
    <li key={index} className={this.getModuleClass(module)} onClick={() => { alert(127) }}>
        <ul className="sb-module-steps-list">
           { module.steps && module.steps.map((stepInfo, stepIndex) =>
               <li key={stepIndex} className={this.getStepClass(stepInfo)}  onClick={() => { alert(456) }}>
                        <p>{stepInfo.short_title}</p>
                      </li>
                      )}
         </ul>
</ul>
```

The problem is that when i click on the innermost child **li** tag,  it triggers onclick event on child as well as the parent.

For example, in this case the click triggers alert(456) and also the parent function alert(123);

I don't want the parent method to run when the child is clicked. Any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`event.stopPropagation()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#overview) to prevent events from bubbling up. Consider this example of a click handler:

```
const handleClick = (event, value) => {
    event.stopPropagation();
    alert(value);
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
<li onClick={event => handleClick(event, 127)}></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the `event` object in your parent's parameter list and use it to prevent what's going to happen:

You can do this:

```
onClick={(e) => { e.target === e.currentTarget && alert(127) }
```

You can (and probably should) use an `if`, which is a little more verbose but easier to understand:

```
onClick={(e) => { if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) return; alert(127) }
```